# How to edit a value based on another in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, if-statement

I have a CSV file with data inside and I want to add 5 to the level if the age is greater than the level

```
Name   Age  Level 
John   40     50
Tom    50     45  
Jerry  45     45
```

My expected output should be

```
Name   Age  Level 
John   40     50
Tom    50     50  
Jerry  45     45
```

I've used this as a starting point, can someone put me in the right direction? I can't seem to work out how to add 5 to the level

```
    if df['age'] > df['level']:
        df['level']+5
        print("levels added")
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your `input` and expected `output`. Please check

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, try using boolean index with .loc and addition assignment operator:

```
df.loc[df['Age']>df['Level'], 'Level'] += 5
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age  Level
0   John   40     50
1    Tom   50     50
2  Jerry   45     45
```